# Converting LULC into fishnet using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid

I am using ArcMap.

I have a LULC and I want to create a fishnet-based LULC out of it. This way, I want to do a grid-based analysis.

Is there any automatic way to do this?

My LULC is a high-resolution one, so there are so many details of LULC. In this regard, there should be a way to assign land cover values by the majority of land cover/use.

This is my LULC and fishnet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a polygon fishnet over your study area using "Create fishnet" tool. Make sure to select Polygon as the geometry type.

Then calculate zonal statistics of the LULC raster over the fishnet using "Zonal statistics as table" tool. Make sure to set the statistics type to Majority. The zone field should be a unique field that identify individual grid.
[image]